# How to convert an Array into String in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to display a base64 image.

I show below how far I've got. `images_base64` is defined like this:

```
def images_base64(images)
  images.map {|image| image.image}
end
```

and if I put it in a paragraph and display it, I get this:

```
["iVBSUhEUAA+gAAA0CAA...a long string"]
```

I use it like this:

```
=image_tag 'data:image/png;base64, '+images_base64(@document.meta.images), width: '450px'
```

I get the error: `No implicit conversion of Array into String`. It seems like I can't convert the returned array into a string.

Comment: Your method `images_base64` returns an array.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh yes I know, I'm asking how can I convert it into a String

Comment: `to_s` would convert it into a string but I don't think you want that. Please explain your issue better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to loop through the images and display them, for example:

```
- images_base64(@document.meta.images).each do |image|
  = image_tag "data:image/png;base64, #{image}", width: '450px'
```

That assumes the 'long string' you're referencing is what you'd like to append to `'data:image/png;base64,`.

That will create an image tag for each element in `images_base64(@document.meta.images)`, which appears to be just one in your example.

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.

Answer (score 1):

A good answer has already been provided and accepted, however let's explain why the error actually threw you off and the question the way it was asked was not really the problem you were trying to solve.

```
"No implicit conversion of Array into String"
```

You're trying to render an array inside of the view which has to end up as a string because HAML gets rendered to an HTML string which is read finally by the browser.  So the simple answer is, when trying to render items inside of an array within a rails view template, you must ITERATE over the array with a `.each` block in ruby, and make sure whatever data ruby returned in that loop can be evaluated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Map is going to return an array so you'll want to index into that array. Since it handles multiple base64 images, you may want to run a loop so that each photo will be displayed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: How does this not answer the question?? Is indexing into an array of strings not the proper way to retrieve a value in the array?

Comment: It is a very vague explanation at best, especially for someone who didn't really understand why they got the error message they posted.  This is not to imply that your answer does not have correctness to it, or that you could have solved the real problem,  but rather that you might have improved your answer based on a comment. "run a loop" is not ruby specific is it?